How do I use an asyncio context manager with Jupyter notebooks to create new tasks?
I have a class called Series, which inherits from a base class called Fred.  Series has a number of methods, which retrieve data from different API end points and process that data into properties of the object.  The base class Fred simply contains a method for retrieving an API key, and methods to format requests and submit them to the server.  I have written all of the relevant "get" methods using asyncio in order to improve the data retrieval time, and if used in a python script or at the iPython console this works fine.  However, I would like this code to be useful in a Jupyter notebook as well.  The issue I am having is that while I can add the task to the existing Jupyter notebook event loop, somewhere in the middle of executing tasks, the async tasks never seem to property return data.
Below is the relevant code:
RUN_FETCH_DATA IS RUN AT INITIALIZATION AND CAN BE RERUN:
def run_fetch_data(self, *args):
        try:
            loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        except RuntimeError:  # 'RuntimeError: There is no current event loop...'
            loop = None

        if loop and loop.is_running():
            print('Async event loop already running. Adding coroutine to the event loop.')
            loop.create_task(self.async_fetch_data(*args, current_loop=loop))
            # # ^-- https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-object
        else:
            print('Starting new event loop')
            asyncio.run(self.async_fetch_data(*args))
        return self

SUPPORTING FUNCTION 1 (NOTE: if kwargs is not provided, this returns the correct data):
    async def async_fetch_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not args:
            tasks = [self._fetch_series_info,
                     self._fetch_series_release_info,
                     self._fetch_series_vintagedates,
                     self._fetch_series_categories,
                     self._fetch_series_tags,
                     self._fetch_series_observations]
        else:
            tasks = []
            if 'info' in args:
                tasks.append(self._fetch_series_info)
            else:
                pass
            if 'release_info' in args:
                tasks.append(self._fetch_series_release_info)
            else:
                pass
            if 'categories' in args:
                tasks.append(self._fetch_series_categories)
            else:
                pass
            if 'observations' in args:
                tasks.append(self._fetch_series_observations)
            else:
                pass
            if 'vintagedates' in args:
                tasks.append(self._fetch_series_vintagedates)
            if 'tags' in args:
                tasks.append(self._fetch_series_tags)
            else:
                pass
        if not kwargs or kwargs is None:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession(self._url_base) as session:
                async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
                    for task in tasks:
                        tg.create_task(task(session))
        elif 'current_loop' in kwargs.keys():
            loop = kwargs['current_loop']
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession(self._url_base) as session:
                for task in tasks:
                    loop.create_task(task(session))
        else:
            raise ValueError('Keyword argument "current_loop" not found in kwargs')
        return self

SUPPORTING FUNCTION 2 (other functions called in tasks are similar to this)
async def _fetch_series_info(self, session):
        try:
            raw_response = await self._async_fetch_data(session, self._series_info_path,
                                                  f'series_id={self.series_id}',
                                                        **self._url_options)
            if isinstance(raw_response, dict):
                raw_response = raw_response['seriess'][0]
            elif isinstance(raw_response, ET.Element):
                raw_response = raw_response[0].attrib
            else:
                raise TypeError('Fred response was neither JSON nor XML, series info get failed')
            setattr(self, 'series_name', raw_response['title'])
            setattr(self, 'observation_start', dt.date.fromisoformat(raw_response['observation_start']))
            setattr(self, 'observation_end', dt.date.fromisoformat(raw_response['observation_end']))
            setattr(self, 'frequency', raw_response['frequency_short'])
            setattr(self, 'units', raw_response['units_short'])
            setattr(self, 'seasonality_adjustment', raw_response['seasonal_adjustment_short'])
            setattr(self, 'series_notes', raw_response['notes'])
            setattr(self, 'update_info', dt.datetime.fromisoformat(raw_response['last_updated']))
        except TypeError:
            print(f'Error fetching info for series {self.series_id}')
        except HTTPError as http_msg:
            # TODO: verify that this actually picks up the HTTPError from parent class
            print(http_msg)
        finally:
            return self

SUPPORTING FUNCTION 3 (this is the base caller function in the Fred base class):
async def _async_fetch_data(self, session: aiohttp.ClientSession,
                                query_path: str, query: str = '', **kwargs) -> dict | ET.ElementTree | ValueError:
        """
        Internal function used to get and parse requests from FRED server

        Parameters
        ----------
        target_url : str
            the target url including any options for the retrieval of information from FRED

        Returns
        -------
        response : dict, XT.Element
            JSON: a dictionary containing the searched data.
            XML: an Element Tree or Element Tree.Element containing searched data.
        """
        request_parse = url_parse.urlparse(Fred._url_base)
        query_options = {'api_key': self.api_key,
                         'file_type': self._default_response_type,
                         'max_response_per_request': self._max_response_per_request,
                         'realtime_start': (self.realtime_start if self.realtime_start is not None else self._earliest_realtime_start),
                         'realtime_end': (self.realtime_end if self.realtime_end is not None else self._latest_realtime_end)}
        if self.observation_end is not None:
            query_options['observation_end'] = str(self.observation_end)
        if self.observation_start is not None:
            query_options['observation_start'] = str(self.observation_start)
        for kw, arg in kwargs.items():
            if self.check_optional_request_parameters(kw, arg):
                query_options[kw] = arg
        target_path = ''.join([query_path, '?', query, '&', url_parse.urlencode(query_options)])
        target_url = url_parse.urlunparse((url_parse.urlparse(Fred._url_base)
                         ._replace(path=url_parse.urljoin(request_parse.path, query_path))
                         ._replace(query=''.join([query,'&',url_parse.urlencode(query_options)]))))
        try:
            async with session.get(target_path) as raw_response:
                if query_options['file_type'] == 'json':
                    response = await raw_response.json()
                else:
                    response = ET.fromstring(await raw_response.text())
        except HTTPError as msg:
            response = ET.fromstring(msg.read())
            raise ValueError(response.get('message'))
        return response


I'm at a loss how you expect the community to help you.  In your description of FUNCTION 1, you tell us that if kwargs is not provided, the data is correct.  Presumably you don't need any help with that situation.  So, why don't you tell us something about the case that doesn't work?  What happens?

@PaulCornelius the issue is when a loop is passed into Function 1.  Assume you are running a Jupyter notebook with an existing event loop.  run_fetch_data attempts to get that loop and pass it to Function 1 as a kwarg.  Function 1 then adds each task to the existing loop (which was passed in).  This appears to work initially, however when the "get" is performed by session, the function exits without retrieving the data and without specifying any error.  Basically, if you pass the running loop in and try to add to it, it doesn't seem to execute the new task.

@PaulCornelius  Based on some debugging, I think that the task being added to the event loop is actually being added, but then not executed.  I am guessing this is some type of product of how Jupyter handles async event loops or interacts with aiohttp.ClientSession.  As a side note, I think I should probably clean up Function 1 so that the "case" switching between having an existing loop and needing a new loop is handled in a clearer manner.

I think I see the problem.  In the case where 'current_loop' is in kwargs, you add the tasks inside a ClientSession context manager.  You exit from that context manager as soon as you have added all the Tasks, without actually running any of the Tasks.  I suspect that the ClientSession gets closed by the context manager on exit, and so none of the Tasks actually runs.  Compare with the other case, where an inner context manager (TaskGroup) will not exit without awaiting the completion of all its Tasks.  One solution is just to insert a call to asyncio.gather(...) inside the ClientSession.
